# Matching JFETs for differential amplifier application

Tags: transistors, jfet

How to choose a properly matched pair of JFETs for differential amplifier? Is it enough to measure their Idss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be on the safest side both \$I_\text{DSS}\$ and \$V_\text{P}\$ should be checked and matched, it is well known that those two JFET's main parameters usually spread widely.

What is less known is that they are strongly correlated, at least for same manufacuter and lot.

A look to this \$I_\text{DSS}=f(V_\text{P})\$ scatter plot done on over 200  different JFET may clarify
[image]
[( source viva-ananlog.com)](http://viva-analog.com/characterizing-and-matching-2n5457-jfet-transistors/)

matching for \$I_\text{DSS}\$ will most likely accomplish good \$V_\text{P}\$ consistance too, and viceversa.

Then you have to known your circuit requirements, how much unbalance you may tolerate and eventually include some trimming if not confident.

Answer (score 1):

Idss would be one of the most important parameters to match. however, it is much better to design your circuit so that it isn't critically dependent on matching jfets.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for a guy who designed telemetry systems for aircraft flight tests.
One mode for customer's telemetry was programmable gain amplifiers, with need to reject the aircraft's 400Hz power electric/magnetic fields by at least 120dB.
With differential inputs through differential FET switches, from hundreds of external sensors. To achieve high-Zin, and thus very low voltage drop across the channel muxing FETS, thus minimal imbalance to sustain high CMRR, he used JFETs.

The PCB used Harris opamps and ADI matched JFETs. He had the chief technician evaluate several of the matched pairs, over temperature and Idd, and record how the Drain voltage drops became imbalanced ----- searching for that magic Idd where the microVolts/degree Centigrade offset-voltage-drift became ZERO.